# Javascript onclick requires two clicks, then creates an increasing amount of server requests

Tags: javascript, onclick

So I'm trying to create a javascript function which fetches a php page and displays it in div in another part of the page. I have managed to achieve this but the clicked_id method I am using requires initially two clicks to register the Id and then subsequently send the number of time it has been clicked so far as a request on every subsequent click. Any help would bve appreciated.

```
<script src="/javascript/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="demo.js"></script>
<link href="demo.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

```
<div id="tabs" ><?php include "tabMenu.php"; ?></div>
<div id="menu"><?php include "menuB.php"; ?></div>
<div id="body" ></div>
<div id="home"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

```
var click_id;
var clickId = function(a) {
    var obj = a;
    var clicks = '#' + obj;
    $(clicks).click(function() {
        $("#home").load("body/" + obj + ".php");
    });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#home').is(':empty')) {
        $("#home").load("body/call.php")
    };

    clickId(click_id); {};
});
```

the tab menu is loaded with php

```
<?php
    $content = file('tabMenu.txt');
    echo '<ul>';
    $click= array(
        'id="call" onClick="clickId(this.id)"',
        'id="policy" onClick="clickId(this.id)"',
        'id="client" onClick="clickId(this.id)"',
        'id="ifa" onClick="clickId(this.id)"'
    );

    foreach (array_combine($click,$content) as $code => $lines ) {
        echo  ('<li '.$code.'>' . $lines . '</li>');
    };

    echo'</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. `click_id` is never assigned a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have confused what `$(clicks).click()` does – if you put it in the right part of your code it will do the same thing you are doing with your `onClick="clickId(this.id)"` and that is why you are getting multiple clicks.

The simplest way to solve the problem is by replacing this code:

```
$(clicks).click(function() {
    $("#home").load("body/" + obj + ".php");
});
```

with this code:

```
$("#home").load("body/" + obj + ".php");
```